# A label in a UIViewController, which refreshes every new view, with a new text

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, label

Every time you come to this view it should be always be random text.

I was searching for the script but I founded nothing!

Screenshot of the App: http://copticmovies.net/iphone/iphone5-video-logo.png

Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you have any questions or is that to promote your website?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This should be a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have a UILabel in your view controller called 'myLabel', a quick and not-very elegant way to do it is:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //quick and dirty random string generation
    NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:20];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 20; i++) {
        u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
        unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
    }

    self.myLabel.text = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an outlet to the label (eg rdmtext).
In your Viewcontroller edit the method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.rdmtext.text = @"Your random text from any source";
}
```

For further details you should add what kind of random text you want to add. Where is it stored?